# Unable to write at correct position in table cell because of a div

Tags: javascript, css, html-table, resize

I have an example code at [codepen](https://codepen.io/your_daddy/pen/povaVrK) of my hobby test project. The resizing of the table here works quite fine but writing in the first row is a horrible experience. This is because of the div I put in each cell in the first row to be able to have something to resize the table with. How do I make it so that the div is just a grab thingy and not something that messes with the actual cell function? Answer must be in plain vanilla javascript, no jQuery or other libraries by the way.

Code:

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<!-- Required meta tags -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
<script src="javascript.js"></script>
<!--- <script src="jquery-3.4.1.js"></script> -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<title>Resizable table hobby testing</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div contenteditable="true" style="width: 500px; height: 500px;"></div>
    <button onclick="insert_table(5, 5);">insert table</button>
</body>
</html>
```

styles.css

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

table, tr, td {
  border: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
}

tr, td {
    width: 60px;
    height: 16px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 3px;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
}
```

javascript.js

```
var th_element;
var startOffset;

function insert_table(rows, cols) { // inserts a table into the div
    // gets the selected text inside the content editable div and deletes it
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
    range.deleteContents();
    // Create a table element
    var ins_table = document.createElement("table");
    // set unique id, useful for getting the element later
    ins_table.setAttribute("id", "table"); // maybe change to ins_table.id = "table";? (note to self)
    // Create the format of rows and columns for the table
    for(var r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
        ins_table.innerHTML += "<tr></tr>";
        ins_table.childNodes[r].innerHTML = "<tr>" + '<td style="min-width: 30px;"> </td>'.repeat(cols) + "</tr>";
    }

    // general css styling
    ins_table.style.width = "200px";
    ins_table.style.float = "left";

    // insert table into cursor position
    range.insertNode(ins_table);

    // get the table by finding its id
    var the_table = document.getElementById('table');

    // get the first row, in order to add a div there that acts as a resize bar grab thingy
    var row = table.getElementsByTagName('tr')[0];
    var cols = row.childNodes; // the cols is all the child nodes of the first row

    for(var i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) { // iterate through all cols and insert the resize grab thingt
        var div = create_div(the_table.offsetHeight); // create a div for the selected cell with the height of the table
        cols[i].appendChild(div); // append that div to the cell
        cols[i].style.position = "relative"; // change position
        cols[i].style.overflow = "visible"; // needs to be set as visible to actually be used on the other rows. Without this it only works with the first row
        add_listener(div, cols[i]); // add a listener
    }
}

function create_div(height){ // create the div the user grabs onto
    var div = document.createElement('div'); // create the resize div to grab onto later
    // general styling
    div.style.top = 0;
    div.style.right = 0;
    div.style.width = '5px';
    div.style.position = 'absolute';
    div.style.cursor = 'col-resize';
    div.style.userSelect = 'none';
    div.style.height = height + 'px';
    div.className = 'columnSelector';
    div.style.border = "none";
    return div; // return the created div, to be inserted into the cell above
}

function add_listener(div, col) {
    div.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
        th_element = col;
        startOffset = col.offsetWidth - event.pageX;
    });

    document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
        if(th_element) {
            th_element.style.width = startOffset + event.pageX + 'px';
        }
    });

    document.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
        th_element = undefined;
    });
}
```